# Rule of Thumb for minimum length of time series for Autocorrection estimation

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, small-sample

I had a related question answered here:

[Rule of Thumb for minimum length of time series for AR(1) estimation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114190/rule-of-thumb-for-minimum-length-of-time-series-for-ar1-estimation)

However the answer gives rise to a new question. I want to be able to estimate the Auto correlation at lag 1 for different step sizes.

While I agree that in theory if the lag 1 auto correlation for step size one is $\phi$ then the lag 1 auto correlation for a step size h should be $\phi^h$. However I want to test this empirically to see if it is in fact the case.

From the testing I have done it seems that for smaller step sizes the theoretical relationship holds in the empirical data set, but as the step size gets larger it starts to deviate (and also to oscillate) so I think at least partly what I am seeing is the noise associated with estimating the lag 1 auto correlation on a small time series.

Is there a formula or even a rule of thumb that I can use to decide what is an acceptable time series length for a lag 1 auto correlation estimation?

Comment: What distinction you are trying to make between a lag-one autocorrelation coefficient at step size $h$ and a lag-$h$ autocorrelation coefficient?

Comment: None. I simply want to check that the power law ascaling does indeed hold. The problem is when you use the larger h's in the log-h correlation coefficient you have the same problem a lack of data points.

Comment: I guess if you are using a decent package, there should be confidence bands on ACF that allow you to assess the goodness of fit.

Comment: Thanks James can you clarify what you mean by confidence bands? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlogram shows two definitions the first is constant across all maturities so is clearly not what I want, but the second one although it increases with lag only appears to consider the uncertainty arising from the previous estimates of the intervening auto correlations, it doesn't seem to have any sensitivity to the amount of measurements used in each calculation.

Comment: Therefore it doesn't seem that I could use it to figure out the max number of lags I can use for a given series length. Or did you have some other definition of confidence band in mind.